# Creating a custom powershell module without exposing code

Tags: powershell

I want to create a custom powershell module that I can distribute without exposing the code.  The script includes API calls with app specific private keys that I don't want to compromise.  I've seen a lot of discussions about this over the years, but nothing that really solves my problem.

Is there a good way to create a custom powershell module without exposing the underlying code?  I want to be able to distribute the powershell module, for others to import or install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this may be what you are looking for : https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ps2exe/1.0.11
but be careful, the API key will still be in the compiled file at someplace. You can try and cipher it, but if it's needed for your script, it will be in your file no matter how you try to hide it. the question is why do you need to ship it inside your script in the first place ? I mean that any of your script's user will be using your **private** key which is likely not what you want to do

Comment: I believe ps2exe is used for individual scripts, not modules.  I was aware of this package, and I've used it before, but I don't think it will accomplish what I'm looking for.  However, you make a great point about the private keys that is making me rethink the design.